# return continuous set of IDs based on two other columns

Tags: postgresql, gaps-and-islands

Given a table such as the one below, how can I ask PostgreSQL to return the first set of `n` rows in which one column has a certain value (`code=0`) and the values of the second column (named `segment`) are all the same, *and the sequence of IDs is not broken*.

For `n=4`, the result should be `id`'s `12, 13, 14, 15` (i.e. the first four `id`'s where `code=0` and the values of `segment` are the same - in this case `2`).

```
CREATE TABLE foo
AS
  SELECT *
  FROM ( VALUES
    (  1, 0, 0 ),
    (  2, 0, 0 ),
    (  3, 0, 0 ),
    (  4, 0, 1 ),
    (  5, 0, 1 ),
    (  6, 0, 1 ),
    (  7, 1, 1 ),
    (  8, 0, 1 ),
    (  9, 1, 2 ),
    ( 10, 0, 2 ),   
    ( 11, 1, 2 ),
    ( 12, 0, 2 ), -- HERE
    ( 13, 0, 2 ), -- HERE
    ( 14, 0, 2 ), -- HERE
    ( 15, 0, 2 ), -- HERE
    ( 16, 0, 3 )
  ) AS t(id,code,segment);
```

Comment: *note that it can't return 10, 12, 13, 14*, you mean *note that it can't return 10, 11, 12, 13*?

Comment: Also, PostgreSQL doesn't have gappless sequences, so *and the sequence of IDs is not broken* is going to be near-useless. You sure that isn't supposed to read *and the sequence of "segment" is not broken*

Comment: is your `n` limited? Or it is a known number not greater then a certain value (say 10)?

Comment: Thanks to the both of you for answering my question! I am grateful that kind folks like you exert so much effort and care to help others. As both of your solutions yield correct results, I am presently torn as to which to mark "correct".

Comment: I did mean that the values returned could not be `10, 12, 13, 14` - but I now see why that only served to confuse, since it was already clear from the question title and first sentence. I will remove that note.

Comment: `n` is not limited, though it will be in the neighbourhood of 10 or less 99.99% of the time.

Comment: Regarding what is considered *not broken*, I did mean IDs - though perhaps I could have said "*consecutive* sequence of IDs". Anyway, this is indeed the gaps-and-islands problem. Thanks for adding that tag!

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this..

```
SELECT
  array_agg(id),
  code,
  segment,
  grp,
  count(*)
FROM (
  SELECT
    id,
    code,
    segment,
    count(is_reset) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      code,
      segment,
      CASE
        WHEN
          code <> lag(code) OVER (ORDER BY id)
          OR segment <> lag(segment) OVER (ORDER BY id)
        THEN 1
      END AS is_reset
    FROM foo
  ) AS t
) AS g
GROUP BY code, segment, grp;

   array_agg   | code | segment | grp | count 
---------------+------+---------+-----+-------
 {11}          |    1 |       2 |   6 |     1
 {10}          |    0 |       2 |   5 |     1
 {1,2,3}       |    0 |       0 |   0 |     3
 {7}           |    1 |       1 |   2 |     1
 {4,5,6}       |    0 |       1 |   1 |     3
 {16}          |    0 |       3 |   8 |     1
 {8}           |    0 |       1 |   3 |     1
 {12,13,14,15} |    0 |       2 |   7 |     4
 {9}           |    1 |       2 |   4 |     1
(9 rows)
```

To query this, just search for `code = 0 AND count >= 4`.

## Explanation

First we generate a reset

```
SELECT
  id,
  code,
  segment,
  CASE
    WHEN
      code <> lag(code) OVER (ORDER BY id)
      OR segment <> lag(segment) OVER (ORDER BY id)
    THEN 1
  END AS is_reset
FROM foo

 id | code | segment | is_reset 
----+------+---------+----------
  1 |    0 |       0 |         
  2 |    0 |       0 |         
  3 |    0 |       0 |         
  4 |    0 |       1 |        1
  5 |    0 |       1 |         
  6 |    0 |       1 |         
  7 |    1 |       1 |        1
  8 |    0 |       1 |        1
  9 |    1 |       2 |        1
 10 |    0 |       2 |        1
 11 |    1 |       2 |        1
 12 |    0 |       2 |        1
 13 |    0 |       2 |         
 14 |    0 |       2 |         
 15 |    0 |       2 |         
 16 |    0 |       3 |        1
(16 rows)
```

Then we create groups,

```
  SELECT
    id,
    code,
    segment,
    count(is_reset) OVER (ORDER BY id) AS grp
  FROM (
    SELECT
      id,
      code,
      segment,
      CASE
        WHEN
          code <> lag(code) OVER (ORDER BY id)
          OR segment <> lag(segment) OVER (ORDER BY id)
        THEN 1
      END AS is_reset
    FROM foo
  ) AS t;
 id | code | segment | grp 
----+------+---------+-----
  1 |    0 |       0 |   0
  2 |    0 |       0 |   0
  3 |    0 |       0 |   0
  4 |    0 |       1 |   1
  5 |    0 |       1 |   1
  6 |    0 |       1 |   1
  7 |    1 |       1 |   2
  8 |    0 |       1 |   3
  9 |    1 |       2 |   4
 10 |    0 |       2 |   5
 11 |    1 |       2 |   6
 12 |    0 |       2 |   7
 13 |    0 |       2 |   7
 14 |    0 |       2 |   7
 15 |    0 |       2 |   7
 16 |    0 |       3 |   8
(16 rows)
```

Now you'll notice that the groups a fn(code,segment), reseting when either changes. Now we group by the `grp`, and do a `count(*)`, but because you want the ids we run them through `array_agg` and store them as an array.

Note, you say *and the sequence of IDs is not broken.* I'm working off the assumption that this is not what you meant. PostgreSQL doesn't have a concept of gapless sequences, so that's not a good idea anyway. I assume you wanted what I've done.

Answer (score 1):

Here is my solution. It is different to Evan's, as I am using the lag() function to get the previous values, and then using the recursive cte to check if the previous values are the same.

The first foorn cte is where I initialise the previous code and segment. I also use the `rn` column for the row_number() in case your ids are not continuous.

The second cte `a` is where I check if the previous code/segment equal to the current code/segment and increase the level `lvl` value.

The third cte `b` is basically where you set what level you need. There you can pass your variable to select the first set for the required level `n`

```
with recursive foorn as(
select *
,lag(code, 1) over(order by id) pre_code
,lag(segment, 1) over(order by id) pre_segment
,row_number() over(order by id) rn
from foo)
, a (id, code, segment, pre_code, pre_segment, rn, min_rn, lvl) as(
select *
,rn as min_rn
,1 as lvl
from foorn where rn=1
union all 
select foorn.id, foorn.code, foorn.segment 
,foorn.pre_code
,foorn.pre_segment
,foorn.rn
,case when foorn.code=foorn.pre_code and foorn.segment=foorn.pre_segment then a.min_rn else foorn.rn end as min_rn
,case when foorn.code=foorn.pre_code and foorn.segment=foorn.pre_segment then a.lvl+1 else 1 end as lvl
from a inner join foorn on a.rn+1=foorn.rn
)
, b as(
select * 
from a 
where lvl = 4 --- <- set the `n` here
order by id limit 1)
select foorn.id, foorn.code, foorn.segment 
from foorn
cross join b
where foorn.rn >= b.min_rn and foorn.rn <= b.rn;
```

results for n=4:

```
 id | code | segment
----+------+---------
 12 |    0 |       2
 13 |    0 |       2
 14 |    0 |       2
 15 |    0 |       2
```